# Using multiple js files generated by flatbuffers in electron/webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, flatbuffers

I have a question regarding using code generated for javascript with flatbuffers.

Now I have `item.fbs` and `itemManager.fbs` which contains a `table` including a vector of `item.fbs`. And it generated 2 js files. When using the itemManager in js, it would throw error of not finding `item` constructor `events.js:163 Uncaught TypeError: my.namespace.Item is not a constructor`. I didn' t find any code regarding importing `item_generated.js` in `item_manager_generated.js`. I' m wondering how to use it properly in ES6 (with the template of https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) ? Declaring both `item` and `itemManager` in a single flatbuffers file and import this file works well.

Comment: Does `itemManager.fbs` contain `include "item.fbs"` ? Generally this should work. You could report an issue on the FlatBuffers github site with some more information (.fbs files). A workaround may be to include `item_generated.js` manually before `item_manager_generated.js`.

Comment: Thanks. https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/4548 shows the fbs files. I' m quite new to the webpack js stuff and not sure how to include that globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I workaround this by using the `--gen-all` flag when using `flatc` to compile the schema files for now.